# How to list subscriptions with current azure credential (without registering app) using C#

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-authentication

I am trying to create multiple VMs to multiple Subscriptions programmatically. So I need to list all subscriptions that I can access. But I cannot grant permissions to registered app, so I have to use my own Azure credential.

Then I tried

```
var subscriptionClient = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.SubscriptionClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

and

```
var subscriptionClient = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.SubscriptionClient(new UserPasswordCredential(username,password));
```

but none of them compiles.

The answer of question [How to list subscriptions with Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689689/how-to-list-subscriptions-with-microsoft-azure-resourcemanager) is almost the answer of my question, but I cannot add comment to ask more question about it.

I installed Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory version 3.13.2.870 and tried:

```
 var ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
```

but ctx doesn't have AcquireToken, it only has AcquireTokenAsync. Unfortunately the following code still doesn't work

```
var mainAuthRes = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(m_resource, m_clientId, new Uri(m_redirectURI), PromptBehavior.Always);
```

The compiler says the fourth parameter is wrong which means

```
context.AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, string client , Uri uri , PromptBehavior promptBehavior )
```

is not a valid method.

Is there any way to list subscriptions with my current azure credential (without registering app) using C#?

Comment: The answer you mentioned looks correct, could you show the details of your error message instead of something like `but all failed`, `still doesn't work`?They are useless.

Comment: It doesn't compile. The constructor of  SubscriptionClient needs a RestClient as its parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code works for me, it uses the [`VisualStudioCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet) of [`Azure.Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity?view=azure-dotnet) to auth, it will list all the subscriptions in all the AAD tenants that you can access(the user account logged in VS).

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VisualStudioCredential tokenCredential = new VisualStudioCredential();
            TokenRequestContext requestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://management.azure.com" });
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var accessToken = tokenCredential.GetToken(requestContext, cts.Token);
            ServiceClientCredentials serviceClientCredentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken.Token);
            SubscriptionClient SubscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(serviceClientCredentials);
            var tenants = SubscriptionClient.Tenants.List();
            foreach (var tenant in tenants)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(tenant.TenantId);
                VisualStudioCredentialOptions visualStudioCredentialOptions = new VisualStudioCredentialOptions{ TenantId = tenant.TenantId };
                VisualStudioCredential tokenCredential1 = new VisualStudioCredential(visualStudioCredentialOptions);
                TokenRequestContext requestContext1 = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://management.azure.com" });
                CancellationTokenSource cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var accessToken1 = tokenCredential1.GetToken(requestContext, cts1.Token);
                ServiceClientCredentials serviceClientCredentials1 = new TokenCredentials(accessToken1.Token);
                SubscriptionClient SubscriptionClient1 = new SubscriptionClient(serviceClientCredentials1);
                var subs = SubscriptionClient1.Subscriptions.List();
                foreach (var sub in subs)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(sub.DisplayName);
                    Console.WriteLine($"SubscriptionName : {sub.DisplayName}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"SubscriptionId   : {sub.SubscriptionId}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"TenantId         : {tenant.TenantId}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"State            : {sub.State}");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }
        }
            
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `SubscriptionClient SubscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(serviceClientCredentials);` doesn't compile. What is the namespace of SubscriptionClient? I tried Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.SubscriptionClient, but it doesn't compile

Comment: @MilhouseManastorm Not that, it is `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager`, a preview version, nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the REST API [Subscriptions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01
```

Request Header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access token>
```

**Update:**

The simplest way to get access token is open the link [Subscriptions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) and sign in with your account.

Then click "try it" at the top right of the script.

[image]

You will find the access token in Request preview.

[image]

Comment: How to get the access token?

Comment: @Milhouse Manastorm I have updated my answer~

Comment: The token will expire in the future